# Python for matching paper IDs in Scholarly

Tags: python

I have a list of the following authors for Google Scholar papers: `Zoe Pikramenou, James H. R. Tucker, Alison Rodger, Timothy Dafforn`. I want to extract and print titles for the papers present for **at least** 3 of these.

You can get a dictionary of paper info from each author using Scholarly:

```
from scholarly import scholarly
AuthorList = ['Zoe Pikramenou', 'James H. R. Tucker', 'Alison Rodger', 'Timothy Dafforn']
for Author in AuthorList:
    search_query = scholarly.search_author(Author)
    author = next(search_query).fill()
    print(author)
```

The output looks something like (just a small excerpt from what you'd get from one author)

```
                  {'bib': {'cites': '69',
         'title': 'Chalearn looking at people and faces of the world: Face '
                  'analysis workshop and challenge 2016',
         'year': '2016'},
 'filled': False,
 'id_citations': 'ZhUEBpsAAAAJ:_FxGoFyzp5QC',
 'source': 'citations'},
                  {'bib': {'cites': '21',
         'title': 'The NoXi database: multimodal recordings of mediated '
                  'novice-expert interactions',
         'year': '2017'},
 'filled': False,
 'id_citations': 'ZhUEBpsAAAAJ:0EnyYjriUFMC',
 'source': 'citations'},
                  {'bib': {'cites': '11',
         'title': 'Automatic habitat classification using image analysis and '
                  'random forest',
         'year': '2014'},
 'filled': False,
 'id_citations': 'ZhUEBpsAAAAJ:qjMakFHDy7sC',
 'source': 'citations'},
                  {'bib': {'cites': '10',
         'title': 'AutoRoot: open-source software employing a novel image '
                  'analysis approach to support fully-automated plant '
                  'phenotyping',
         'year': '2017'},
 'filled': False,
 'id_citations': 'ZhUEBpsAAAAJ:hqOjcs7Dif8C',
 'source': 'citations'}
```

How can I collect the `bib` and specifically `title` for papers which are present for three or more out of the four authors?

EDIT: in fact it's been pointed out `id_citations` is not unique for each paper, my mistake. Better to just use `title` itself

Comment: I've played around with this data and there are 744 total publications, with 744 unique ids, and 687 unique titles. So either there is not much overlap between authors here or the id field does not work how you thought it does.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz could you share your code for collecting the unique IDs/titles?

Comment: Sure. I first take the publications per author (as dictionaries since pandas doesn't understand scholarly objects) and create a Pandas DataFrame: `df = pd.DataFrame([x.__dict__ for x in author.publications])`. I then assign a new column to track the author: `df['author'] = Author`. I then append to a list of frames: `frames.append(df)`. Then outside of the loop you concatenate all of them to one DataFrame: `all_authors = pd.concat(frames, axis=0)`. From here you can explore the data using Pandas. If you have no experience with Pandas I can make another comment explaining how to count uniques.

Comment: Thanks. I have a little experience with Pandas. I'm not sure where your answer starts though (```author.publications``` is generated only for a specific ```author``` in the AuthorList, so are you are in the for-loop? Did you initialise ```frames``` beforehand? etc.). It doesn't seem a long way to go from your answer to what I asked so maybe make a full answer with it. And show titles that are repeated >=2 times? I'll look into id_citations for those

Comment: Sure I'll write up a quick answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you can achieve this using Pandas groupby:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scholarly import scholarly

AuthorList = ['Zoe Pikramenou', 'James H. R. Tucker', 'Alison Rodger', 'Timothy Dafforn']
frames = []

for Author in AuthorList:
    search_query = scholarly.search_author(Author)
    author = next(search_query).fill()
    # creating DataFrame with authors
    df = pd.DataFrame([x.__dict__ for x in author.publications])
    df['author'] = Author
    frames.append(df.copy())

# joining all author DataFrames
df = pd.concat(frames, axis=0)

# taking bib dict into separate columns
df[['title', 'cites', 'year']] = pd.DataFrame(df.bib.to_list())

# counting unique authors attached to each title
n_authors = df.groupby('title').author.nunique()
# locating the unique titles for all publications with n_authors >= 2
output = n_authors[n_authors >= 2].index
```

This finds 202 papers which have 2 or more of the authors in that list (out of 774 total papers). Here is an example of the output:

```py
Index(['1, 1′-Homodisubstituted ferrocenes containing adenine and thymine nucleobases: synthesis, electrochemistry, and formation of H-bonded arrays',
       '722: Iron chelation by biopolymers for an anti-cancer therapy; binding up the'ferrotoxicity'in the colon',
       'A Luminescent One-Dimensional Copper (I) Polymer',
       'A Unidirectional Energy Transfer Cascade Process in a Ruthenium Junction Self-Assembled by r-and-Cyclodextrins',
       'A Zinc(II)-Cyclen Complex Attached to an Anthraquinone Moiety that Acts as a Redox-Active Nucleobase Receptor in Aqueous Solution',
       'A ditopic ferrocene receptor for anions and cations that functions as a chromogenic molecular switch',
       'A ferrocene nucleic acid oligomer as an organometallic structural mimic of DNA',
       'A heterodifunctionalised ferrocene derivative that self-assembles in solution through complementary hydrogen-bonding interactions',
       'A locking X-ray window shutter and collimator coupling to comply with the new Health and Safety at Work Act',
       'A luminescent europium hairpin for DNA photosensing in the visible, based on trimetallic bis-intercalators',
       ...
       'Up-Conversion Device Based on Quantum Dots With High-Conversion Efficiency Over 6%',
       'Vectorial Control of Energy‐Transfer Processes in Metallocyclodextrin Heterometallic Assemblies',
       'Verteporfin selectively kills hypoxic glioma cells through iron-binding and increased production of reactive oxygen species',
       'Vibrational Absorption from Oxygen-Hydrogen (Oi-H2) Complexes in Hydrogenated CZ Silicon',
       'Virginia review of sociology',
       'Wildlife use of log landings in the White Mountain National Forest',
       'Yttrium 1995',
       'ZUSCHRIFTEN-Redox-Switched Control of Binding Strength in Hydrogen-Bonded Metallocene Complexes Stichworter: Carbonsauren. Elektrochemie. Metallocene. Redoxchemie …',
       '[2] Rotaxanes comprising a macrocylic Hamilton receptor obtained using active template synthesis: synthesis and guest complexation',
       'pH-controlled delivery of luminescent europium coated nanoparticles into platelets'],
      dtype='object', name='title', length=202)
```

Since all of the data is in Pandas, you can also explore what the attached authors on each of the papers is as well as all of the other information you have access to within the `author.publications` array coming in from scholarly.

Comment: Thanks very much. You're right--I was mistaken in thinking ```id_citations``` is a unique identifier for a given paper, thanks for pointing this out. I'll update my post. Could you update yours to instead list those **titles** which are common to >=2 authors from the list?

Comment: This answer does list titles which are common to >= 2 authors from the list, I just haven't pasted the full list since it is very long.

Comment: but it does so using commonality of ```id_citations``` which I don't think we can take as representative of anything (my mistake! Sorry). So it would be better just to match on the titles themselves

Comment: As an example: the paper 'Polymerase chain reaction on a viral nanoparticle' was authored by James H. R. Tucker, Alison Rodger, and Timothy Dafforn. But the id_citations in scholarly seem to be ```MzV58_UAAAAJ:V3AGJWp-ZtQC```, ```f2R-tsQAAAAJ:_FM0Bhl9EiAC```, ```1BCQGYoAAAAJ:5awf1xo2G04C``` respectively. I was wrong to think we can match based on them.

Comment: Also, does ```author.nunique()``` count the no of authors of the paper, or the no of authors of the paper who are present in the ```AuthorList```? Because the first number would be likely to be much higher

Comment: It only considers authors from AuthorList. I will update my answer using the `title` field for matching publications.

Comment: I'm afraid this seems to produce a very large number of false positives. Try for example ```output = n_authors[n_authors >= 4].index``` which should only have papers all four contributed to. The first result is ```722: Iron chelation by biopolymers for an anti-cancer therapy; binding up the'ferrotoxicity'in the colon'```. If you look up the results for the individual scholars, or search the paper online (e.g. https://www.infona.pl/resource/bwmeta1.element.elsevier-8f795f5e-4e48-3816-a331-4579675b4e04), you'll see that of the authors in AuthorList only Zoe Pikramenou is an author of this paper.

Comment: Actually managed to fix it myself, just had to unpack the ```bib``` dict slightly differently

Comment: do you know, by the way, how I can do something similar for abstracts? So far I have ```for title in output:
    search_query = scholarly.search_pubs(title)
    pub_info = next(search_query)
    df = pd.DataFrame([x.__dict__ for x in pub_info])``` but I get an error ```'Publication' object is not iterable``` on this

Comment: at https://pypi.org/project/scholarly/ under ```search_pubs``` there is an example that shows the output of that function: one ```bib``` per paper

Answer (score 1):

First, let's convert this into a more friendly format. You say that the `id_citations` is unique for each paper, so we'll use it as a hashtable/dict key.

We can then map each `id_citation` to the bib dict and author(s) it appears for, as a list of tuples `(bib, author_name)`.

```
author_list = ['Zoe Pikramenou', 'James H. R. Tucker', 'Alison Rodger', 'Timothy Dafforn']
bibs = {}
for author_name in author_list:
    search_query = scholarly.search_author(author_name)
    for bib in search_query:
        bib = bib.fill()
        bibs.setdefault(bib['id_citations'], []).append((bib, author_name))
```

Thereafter, we can sort the keys in `bibs` based on how many authors are attached to them:

```
most_cited = sorted(bibs.items(), key=lambda k: len(k[1]))
# most_cited is now a list of tuples (key, value)
# which maps to (id_citation, [(bib1, author1), (bib2, author2), ...])
```

and/or filter that list to citations that have only three or more appearances:

```
cited_enough = [tup[1][0][0] for tup in most_cited if len(tup[1]) >= 3]
# using key [0] in the middle is arbitrary. It can be anything in the 
# list, provided the bib objects are identical, but index 0 is guaranteed
# to be there.
# otherwise, the first index is to grab the list rather than the id_citation,
# and the last index is to grab the bib, rather than the author_name
```

and now we can retrieve the titles of the papers from there:

```
paper_titles = [bib['bib']['title'] for bib in cited_enough]
```

Comment: Thanks. But at ```for bib in author``` I get an error ```'Author' object is not iterable```

Comment: ah, I made assumptions from your code, since I don't have `scholarly` myself. Whichever thing is iterable (probably `search_query` instead of `author`, which honestly makes more sense) is the one you should be using. I'll update my answer.

Comment: With ```for bib in search_query``` the final line ```bibs.setdefault(bib['id_citations'], []).append((bib, author_name))``` gives error ```'Author' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: But for example ```print(bib.fill())``` does work (just not for the mapping we want)

Comment: The `author.publications` array is what contains the bib objects that you wish to iterate over.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz I tried ```author = next(search_query).fill()``` followed by ```for bib in author.publications: bibs.setdefault(bib['id_citations'], []).append((bib, author_name))```

and got error ```'Publication' object is not subscriptable```