# Python for paper abstracts in Scholarly

Tags: python

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683258/python-for-matching-paper-ids-in-scholarly) about using Scholarly to obtain titles where matching across 3+ authors of a given list. There was a good response by user @pciunkiewicz which involved conversion of the Scholarly output to pandas first.

Now I'd like to do this for abstracts. In Scholarly once you've found the author info by

```
search_query = scholarly.search_author('Zoe Pikramenou')
author = next(search_query).fill()
```

you can get the abstracts of author `Zoe Pikramenou` by

```
for i in range(len(author.publications)):
    pub = author.publications[i].fill()
    print(pub)
```

@pciunkiewicz gave code for collecting the titles as follows

```
import pandas as pd
from scholarly import scholarly

AuthorList = ['Zoe Pikramenou', 'James H. R. Tucker', 'Alison Rodger', 'Timothy Dafforn']
frames = []

for Author in AuthorList:
    search_query = scholarly.search_author(Author)
    author = next(search_query).fill()
    # creating DataFrame with authors
    df = pd.DataFrame([x.__dict__ for x in author.publications])
    df['author'] = Author
    frames.append(df.copy())

# joining all author DataFrames
df = pd.concat(frames, axis=0)
```

And once you've got the titles for each author in a df like that, you can easily groupby and restrict to only those titles which have >=2 author count or >=3 author count.

Question I'm now facing is how to get the **abstracts** for these selected papers.

- **EXAMPLE**

The output from my for-loop for abstracts is of the format

```
{'bib': {'abstract': 'The bis(β-diketone) ligands '
                     '1,3-bis(3-phenyl-3-oxopropanoyl)benzene, H2L1 and '
                     '1,3-bis(3-phenyl-3-oxopropanoyl) 5-ethoxy-benzene, H2L2, '
                     'have been prepared for the examination of dinuclear '
                     'lanthanide complex formation and investigation of their '
                     'properties as sensitizers for lanthanide luminescence. '
                     'The ligands bear two conjugated diketonate binding sites '
                     'linked by a 1,3-phenylene spacer. The ligands bind to '
                     'lanthanide(III) or yttrium(III) ions to form neutral '
                     'homodimetallic triple stranded complexes [M2L13] where M '
                     '= Eu, Nd, Sm, Y, Gd and [M2L23], where M = Eu, Nd or '
                     'anionic quadruple-stranded dinuclear lanthanide units, '
                     '[Eu2L14]2- . The crystal structure of the free ligand '
                     'H2L1 has been determined and shows a twisted arrangement '
                     'of the two binding sites around the 1,3-phenylene '
                     'spacer. The dinuclear complexes have been isolated and '
                     'fully characterized. Detailed NMR investigations of the '
                     '…',
         'author': 'Andrew P Bassett and Steven W Magennis and Peter B Glover '
                   'and David J Lewis and Neil Spencer and Simon Parsons and '
                   'René M Williams and Luisa De Cola and Zoe Pikramenou',
         'cites': '9771470119464039345',
         'journal': 'Journal of the American Chemical Society',
         'number': '30',
         'pages': '9413-9424',
         'publisher': 'American Chemical Society',
         'title': 'Highly luminescent, triple-and quadruple-stranded, '
                  'dinuclear Eu, Nd, and Sm (III) lanthanide complexes based '
                  'on bis-diketonate ligands',
         'url': 'https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja048022z',
         'volume': '126',
         'year': '2004'},
 'cites_per_year': {2004: 2,
                    2005: 14,
                    2006: 26,
                    2007: 36,
                    2008: 25,
                    2009: 27,
                    2010: 30,
                    2011: 28,
                    2012: 28,
                    2013: 19,
                    2014: 18,
                    2015: 22,
                    2016: 20,
                    2017: 17,
                    2018: 15,
                    2019: 22,
                    2020: 7},
 'filled': True,
 'id_citations': 'dtt8YyMAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C',
 'source': 'citations'}
{'bib': {'abstract': 'Luminescent Ln−Pt2 metallohairpin complexes have been '
                     'developed, and their intercalative recognition with DNA '
                     'has been demonstrated with linear dichroism '
                     'spectroscopy. The heterotrimetallic complexes were '
                     'formed in a one-step reaction, by assembly of an '
                     'aminopolycarboxylate ligand, a platinum terpyridine '
                     'unit, and the lanthanide salt. The metallohairpin '
                     'complexes bear a neutral lanthanide moiety and two '
                     'positively charged platinum-containing intercalating '
                     'units. The Nd(III) analogues are luminescent in the near '
                     'infrared, and this near-IR luminescence is retained upon '
                     'binding to DNA. The DNA recognition was demonstrated by '
                     'linear dichroism spectroscopy. The linear dichroism '
                     'spectra suggested that the complexes bind perpendicular '
                     'to the DNA helical axis, confirming intercalative '
                     'recognition accompanied by dramatic stiffening of DNA, '
                     'which suggests bis-intercalation of the complex. ',
         'author': 'Peter B Glover and Peter R Ashton and Laura J Childs and '
                   'Alison Rodger and Michael Kercher and René M Williams and '
                   'Luisa De Cola and Zoe Pikramenou',
         'cites': '2742068144437453737',
         'journal': 'Journal of the American Chemical Society',
         'number': '33',
         'pages': '9918-9919',
         'publisher': 'American Chemical Society',
         'title': 'Hairpin-shaped heterometallic luminescent lanthanide '
                  'complexes for DNA intercalative recognition',
         'url': 'https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja029886s',
         'volume': '125',
         'year': '2003'},
 'cites_per_year': {2004: 14,
                    2005: 11,
                    2006: 20,
                    2007: 22,
                    2008: 18,
                    2009: 31,
                    2010: 14,
                    2011: 9,
                    2012: 8,
                    2013: 18,
                    2014: 11,
                    2015: 11,
                    2016: 6,
                    2017: 4,
                    2018: 4,
                    2019: 1,
                    2020: 1},
 'filled': True,
 'id_citations': 'dtt8YyMAAAJ:u-x6o8ySG0sC',
 'source': 'citations'}
```

The output from @pciunkiewicz's code for titles (restricted to >=3 authors) is

```
'Polymerase chain reaction on a viral nanoparticle'
'Use of the M13 viral chassis, fluid dynamics and linear dichroism in pathogen detection'
```

Just two papers. At this point I'd like to extract the abstract from `bib` info (shown for a couple of abstracts above) for just the two papers with the above titles, i.e.

```
'The field of synthetic biology includes studies that aim to develop new materials and devices from biomolecules. In recent years, much work has been carried out using a range of biomolecular chassis including α-helical coiled coils, β-sheet amyloids and even viral particles. In this work, we show how hybrid bionanoparticles can be produced from a viral M13 bacteriophage scaffold through conjugation with DNA primers that can template a polymerase chain reaction (PCR). This unprecedented example of a PCR on a virus particle has been studied by flow aligned linear dichroism spectroscopy, which gives information on the structure of the product as well as a new protototype methodology for DNA detection. We propose that this demonstration of PCR on the surface of a bionanoparticle is a useful addition to ways in which hybrid assemblies may be constructed using synthetic biology.'
<None>
```

(I cannot see that Google Scholar has an abstract for the second paper. In this case there shouldn't be any text of course.)

Of course if the output is another format e.g. the `bib` from the abstract above, that's fine, I can work with that. Any help how to do this?

Comment: @pciunkiewicz any ideas on this? I assume we can do something like making ```output``` the list of titles we want abstracts for, then ```return bib for bib if title in output``` where we just need a way to check the title from ```author.publications[i].fill()```.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand problem but maybe `[ item["bib"]["abstract"] for item in output ]`

Comment: ```item``` in ```output``` would just be a string (the title). you can't index it for ```bib```

Comment: in your `output` you show `{'bib': {'abstract': ...}` so you have two different outputs and you have to use different names to correctly describe which one you mean. - ie `[ item["bib"]["abstract"] for item in your_output if item['title'] in pciunkiewicz_output ]`